# Is there a way to fix ChatGPT Service Error?

Tags: javascript, html

I opened chatGPT to debug my HTML code but it kept saying "Failed to get service"

I want this code to work:

```html
<html>
  <head></head>
  <body>
    <script>
      while True {
        a = randomNumber;
        b = randomNumber;
        c = prompt((a + "+" + b));
        if (c = (a + b)) {
          alert("Correct");
        } else {
          alert("Wrong");
        }
      }
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

I want to code a program which gives a random number + random number math question but the Error says: Undefined Identifier

Comment: Part of the problem is your use of `True` - JS is case sensitive, it's `true`. Secondly, the `while` syntax is wrong. I'd suggest not relying on chatGPT. Also, an infinite loop is an incredibly bad idea in JS.

Comment: The title has nothing to do with the question?

Comment: Why are you asking us to fix ChatGPT instead of just asking your question?

Comment: looks like you need to start out by looking into javascript loops.

I fail to see why you bring chatGPT up, it's ok you use it but it just confuses the picture to mention which advanced search service you used.

second part of the problem is your using of randomNumber, unless you make it so that is not a thing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, it's `while (true) {..}`

Then, if that's all your code, `randomNumber` is nowhere to be found. You can replace it with `Math.floor(Math.random() * 10)` to get a random number between 0 and 10.

You are also missing an extra equal sign in the `if`.

Lastly, you need to `break` the loop when the answer is wrong.

```
while (true) {
  a = Math.floor(Math.random() * 10);
  b = Math.floor(Math.random() * 10);
  c = prompt((a + "+" + b));
  if (c == (a + b)) {
    alert("Correct");
  } else {
    alert("Wrong");
    break;
  }
}
```